# Spring Rest Hibernate OneToMany / ManyToOne

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to create a user table that has a OneToMany relationship using the username as a foreign key, however the username field in the ManyToOne relationship is coming through as Null every time.

Relationships:

```
User:

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Authority.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="username")
    private Collection<Authority> authorities

Authority:

    @Column(nullable = false, name="username")
    @JoinColumn(name="user_username")
    String username;
```

resulting tables:

```
+----+--------------------+-----------+---------+
| id | username           | password  | enabled |
+----+--------------------+-----------+---------+
| 13 | will               | q         |       0 |
| 34 | I just got editted | adufhasdf |       1 |
| 36 | wakakawakwakaak    | ballz     |       0 |
+----+--------------------+-----------+---------+

+----+----------+------------+
| id | username | authority  |
+----+----------+------------+
|  6 | NULL     | ROLE_ADMIN |
|  7 | NULL     | ROLE_ADMIN |
|  8 | NULL     | ROLE_ADMIN |
| 12 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 13 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 14 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 17 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 18 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 19 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 20 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 21 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 22 | NULL     | none       |
| 23 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 24 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 25 | NULL     | none       |
| 26 | NULL     | none       |
| 27 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 28 | NULL     | none       |
| 29 | NULL     | ROLE_ADMIN |
| 30 | NULL     | ROLE_ADMIN |
| 31 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 39 | NULL     | ROLE_BASIC |
| 40 | NULL     | ROLE_USER  |
| 41 | NULL     | ROLE_USER  |
| 42 | NULL     | ROLE_USER  |
| 43 | NULL     | ROLE_ADMIN |
| 44 | NULL     | ROLE_ADMIN |
| 45 | NULL     | ROLE_USER  |
+----+----------+------------+
```

Comment: As my understanding, you would like to use "username" column as Primary key in table "user" and in table "authority", you will have "username" column as foreign key in table "user"?! Or in table "user", you have Primary Key is "id", "username" is just unique ?!

Comment: Username in user is just unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple answer turned up in the JPA docs.

In user

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Authority.class , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="username", referencedColumnName="username")
private List<Authority> authorities
```

and then the Authority

```
@Column(nullable = false)
String username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `JoinColumn` should be:

```
@JoinColumn(name="username")
```

This is because the field is identified as `username` in the `Authority` entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is from the many-to-one side, you have to use the User object instead of the String. Here is what i tried and it works.

//User

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Authority.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
private Collection<Authority> authorities;
```

//Authority

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="username", referencedColumnName = "username")
private User user;
```

Results:

[image]

Hope this help!

Comment: I saw that in some docs and other posts, however I'm kind of married to using the String.